# How to use substrings to extract text from buffered reader

Tags: java, android, bufferedreader, substring

I'm trying to extract text between two tags using substrings and bufferedreader but I get a indexoutofbounds exception. The if statement is used because I am parsing 5 webpages and I want to read text in from each of the webpages, Below is my code:

```
    public static List<WebPage> readRawTextFile(Context ctx, int resId) {
    InputStream inputStream = ctx.getResources().openRawResource(
            R.raw.pages);

    InputStreamReader inputreader = new InputStreamReader(inputStream);
    BufferedReader buffreader = new BufferedReader(inputreader);
    String line;
    StringBuilder text = new StringBuilder();
    String txt1 = text.toString();
    try {
        int count = 0;
        while ((line = buffreader.readLine()) != null) {

            if (line.length() == 0) {
                int sURL = line.indexOf("<!--");
                int eURL = line.indexOf("-->");
                String newSub = txt1.substring(txt1.indexOf(sURL) + 1,
                        txt1.indexOf("\""));
                System.out.println(newSub);
            }
```

Comment: Well, for starters you probably want `line.length() != 0` instead of `line.length() == 0`, right?

Comment: I wanted to use the line.length()=0, so i can seperate the first page by a space and then read text from the first page before carrying on

Comment: Maybe you "wanted to", but that is not what the code is telling the JVM to do.

Answer (score 3):

Look at this code:

```
if (line.length() == 0) {
    int sURL = line.indexOf("<!--");
    int eURL = line.indexOf("-->");
    String newSub = txt1.substring(txt1.indexOf(sURL) + 1,
            txt1.indexOf("\""));
    ...
}
```

You're going into the block *if the line is empty*. So `sURL` and `eURL` will definitely be -1.

You're then using `txt1.indexOf(-1)`, which is odd to start with (why would you use `indexOf` and pass in an index?) - I strongly suspect that both of the `indexOf` values here are going to be -1, so you'll have:

```
String newSub = txt1.substring(0, -1);
```

... which will fail. It's not clear why you're using `txt1.substring` instead of `line.substring` here at all, either.

Basically, I think there's a *bunch* of stuff wrong with your code. You should look at it all *very* carefully, every single line, and change it until it really makes sense. Then add unit tests...

Answer (score 0):

Since `sURL` is already the

```
int sURL = txt1.indexOf("<!--");
```

, then `txt1.indexOf(sURL)` does not make much sense in the

```
String newSub = txt1.substring(txt1.indexOf(sURL) + 1, txt1.indexOf("\""));
```

line, probably you meant something like:

```
String newSub = txt1.substring(sURL + 1, txt1.indexOf("\""));
```

That would only leave the mystery of why you are using `txt1.indexOf("\"")` later.